# How to get the Enterprise token from the Callback URL without redirect it to new tab in the browser?

Tags: android-management-api, callbackurl, android-enterprise

I have a doubt in extracting the Enterprise token. I know I can copy the Enterprise token from the URL. Instead of copying it,Is there anyway to extract the token without opening from the callbackURL? You have mentioned to point to the server in the CALLBACKURL. I'm creating the enterprise for my customer.Hence kindly help me in this.

```
SignupUrl signupUrl =
                androidManagementClient
                .signupUrls()
                .create()
                .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                .setCallbackUrl("https://localhost:3000/enrollmentToken")
                .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems the Android Management API does not provide a method call in the SignupUrl object that can fetch the enterprise token for you. This seems like an API limitation in contrast with the EMM API, which [already does that](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises/generateSignupUrl).